# How to create random angled curves in geonodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to recreate this script (https://github.com/mantissa-/RandoGrid) in geometry nodes and I have some questions.

1. This is what I've got so far:

[image]

This is inside of my NodeGroup:

[image]

And at frame 20 it looks like this:

[image]

So I want to give user a choice on number of repeats. I figured I would do it this way and if user wants 20 repeats then he can go to frame 20.
Is there a better way of doing this or that's how it's suppose to work?

2. If that's how it's suppose to work then I have this problem. Look at number of vertices at frame 20:

[image]

Insane! What am I doing wrong?

3. How do I limit this so it doesn't extrude outside of the initial x and y dimension (5 and 3 in this case) and if it does how to make it choose a diffrent direction?

Comment: About the repeating part, blender version 4.0 will have loops. It's called repeat zone for now. You can check that out by downloading the alpha build.

Comment: Are you sure you need a simulation? Would some cunning weights in _Shortest Edge Paths_ do the trick?  https://imgur.com/a/BeNAMOO

Answer (score 7):

As Robin Betts already pointed out, you don't need a simulation zone or a repeat zone. Here's a solution using *Accumulate Field*:

[image]

[image] [image]

on the 2nd image you can see more horizontal offsets for overlaps, but this technique allows the lines to move away (horizontally) from its starting trajectory (by a lot). If you don't want this to happen, you can just set random positions without accumulation on XY, or use a noise texture to do that if you want an effect in between…

Here's an example how that could look like, this time I'm normalizing the random vector, so the distribution doesn't favor diagonals:

[image]

Also notice dividing the index by 2 and ceiling, to get a consistent random number on points of the vertical segments.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix issue I described in question 2 by adding Merge by Distance node after Join Geometry inside my created NodeGroup.

[image]

Now my loop is properly only adding new geometry instead of doubling it every frame.